# Property 'ɵunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, angular-language-service

> Property 'ɵunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/home/thrymr/Desktop/ILMCT 2/ilmct-frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/index")'.

Project is compiled successfully and running but getting this error wherever I'm using at the place of `[(ngModel)]`. What can be the reason and how to remove this error?

I tried everything like uninstalling my vs code and installing again, cloned project again. Using angular version is 14 and Node.js version is 18

> **Moderator note:** This appears to be a bug in the latest release of the Angular Language IDE extension. Please do not add **new** answers pointing solely to the bug, or telling people to downgrade.

Comment: This is extension - Angular Language Service providing error so either you can uninstall or downgrade the extension version

Comment: seems fixed in 17.2.2 it seems (reload required)

Answer (score 58):

You can roll back to Angular Language Extension **v17.1.1** until the bug is fixed.

Comment: An issue is open on their github: https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/2001

Answer (score 56):

This is origin issus:

There was an update yesterday.

[image]

Steps to go back to a previous version:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

**Edit 15/02/2024**

Apparently they have already fixed the error and there is a new version

[image]

**Edit 05/03/2024**

Some have commented that version 17.2.2 does not work, however I am working with that version, you can verify if it is not another extension that is causing the problem, I will leave an image with the extensions that I have installed with respect to angular, javascript and tscript

[image]
[image]

Another thing you have to verify is that if you are importing the `FormsModule` module, either in the `YouModule.ts` file or in the `Youcomponent.ts` if you are using standalone

Comment: On my side it was just showing the vscode plugin need a restart. After the restart the error disappeared. In fact they just rolled back the 17.2.0 and created a fixed version 17.2.1.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will check the new version

Comment: Downgrading to 17.1.1 and then a reload of VSCode worked for me. Lets wait for the bug to be resolved

Comment: @HassanRaza I tried 17.2.2 and it works

Comment: I still encounter the issue with 17.2.2

Comment: @Kateriine Try version 17.1.1

Comment: FYI, I am also seeing this in 17.2.2. Version 17.2.1 works, so it looks like they broke it again with the latest release.

Comment: @Zach Well, curiously, version 17.2.2 works for me

Comment: 17.2.2 still broken here. Using 17.1.1 for now.

Comment: 17.2.2 still broken as of 2/28/24

Comment: Version 17.2.2 still broken, upgrade up to 17.2.1... At least at 2024-03-05

Answer (score 12):

This just happened to me as well when I updated the angular language service extension , I fixed it by installing  version 17.1.0

Answer (score 7):

Version 17.2.1 of the extension has been published which should fix this. If you don't have an update listed, go to the extension, and click the drop down arrow next to `Uninstall`, then select `Install Another Version`. The new version should be listed at the top.

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs for Angular Language Service VS code extension update.
Just reload the extension or uninstall then install again, it will fix.

Probably VS code extension tab already suggest you to reload the extension.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently they published a new version (v17.2.1) where they roll back the version of the package that is having the issue.

> 17.2.1
> This release rolls back the @angular/language-service version to v17.2.0-next.0 to resolve an issue reported in ticket #2001.

you find the issue here: https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/2001

what you **need** to do now is to update the extension to its **latest version** which is **17.2.1**.

[image: screenshot from the Angular Language Service extension]

Answer (score 0):

In version **v17.2.2** of the Angular Language Extension extension the problem reappears, but the new version **v17.3.1** fixes it again.