# Property 'ɵunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type 'typeof import/node_modules/@angular/core/index")'

Tags: html, angular, node-modules

I have tried the answers given on the previous threads but none of them works can somebody please help on this matter?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'ɵunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77986204/property-%c9%b5unwrapwritablesignal-does-not-exist-on-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is related to **Angular Language Service extension** version of VS code.
You can rollback your **Angular Language Service** extension version to **v17.1.1**.

I have just rolled back my version to v17.1.1 and its working fine for me .