# I am getting errors on ngmodels in angular

Tags: angular, components, ngmodel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8RD9.jpg)
I am new to angular... When I implementing ngmodels I get some errors that property 'eunwrapWritableSignal' does not exist on type..... Like in the picture

Please guys give any suggestions to solve the error

Comment: Have you try restarting the Angular app?

Comment: Show you package.json file please

Comment: Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77986204/property-%C9%B5unwrapwritablesignal-does-not-exist-on-type